# "No such resource" setting activity's theme

Tags: android

I want to display a picture full screen without an action bar in Android tablet, but when I write `android:theme="@android:style/Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen"` in Android Manifest, it says there is no such resource. How is it possible since it is on the list of themes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```